# Style not applying for AlertDialog with DialogFragment

Tags: android-theme, android-dialogfragment

I'm using a `DialogFragment' to display alert dialog. My requirement is to have a same theme for all the dialog fragment's in the appllicaiton across different versions of Android starting from 2.3. But I'm unable to apply theme. My code is

```
<style name="Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyOwnDialogTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyOwnDialogTitle"  parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:drawableRight">@android:drawable/ic_menu_add</item>
</style>
```

```
  public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Dialog);
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
           builder.setTitle("Title");
           builder.setMessage("Message");
           builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
           return builder.create();
        }
 }
```

My output on 2.3 emulator is like

[image]

Please Help me out.

Thanks, 
Sha.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<style name="MyOwnDialogTitle"  parent="android:Widget.TextView">`

by

```
<style name="MyOwnDialogTitle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
```